# restrict pattern to specified strings

Tags: awk

I have a set of strings. Lets say, (list.txt) they are:

```
 1abc_A
 2pqr_X
 4ghi_Z
```

I also have a text file (test.txt), which looks like this:

```
1abc_A    2pqr_X    0.55       0.87
2pqr_X    3def_Y    0.21       0.24
4ghi_Z    1abc_A    0.98       0.75
2pqr_X    4ghi_Z    0.99       0.76
2pqr_X    2pqr_X    1.00       1.00
```

I need to get only those lines from test.txt, such that strings in columns 1 and 2, belong to the strings included in list.txt

In this case, my output would be as follows:

```
1abc_A    2pqr_X    0.55       0.87
4ghi_Z    1abc_A    0.98       0.75
2pqr_X    4ghi_Z    0.99       0.76
2pqr_X    2pqr_X    1.00       1.00
```

i.e all the lines in test.txt EXCEPT the 2nd line, since column 2 in 2nd line, 3def_Y is not among the list of strings specified in list.txt

How can I do this in awk? 
Please note that test.txt is a large text file, of almost 7GB.

What is the fastest way to go about this problem ? 
Please help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} ($1 in a) && ($2 in a)' list.txt test.txt
```

Stores the contents of list.txt as indices of an array, and then line by line of test.txt checks that it's 1st and 2nd fields are both indices of that array. Will work for any size of test.txt as it doesn't store any of test.txt in memory.